# Excel to CSV using POI Event based API - Skip header row( first row in Excel)

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to convert Excel (.xls ,.xlsx) files to CSV using

For xlsx to CSV

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java

For xls to CSV

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hssf/eventusermodel/examples/XLS2CSVmra.java

Everything is fine but I dont want the Header rows in Excel to be written to CSV. **Can someone please help me how I can skip the header row in excel? Atleast how can I get the row number from which I getting the call back events to  the handlers ?** I am in so deperate help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after so much digging I came across a class `XSSFSheetXMLHandler` which gets the row number the following way. So I used this to  know the row number. Its part of the `Attributes`  argument to the startElement method.

```
 else if("row".equals(name)) {
                int rowNum = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("r")) - 1; //This gets the row number. Then based on this value i Set a boolean variable part of the class member variable.
                if(rowNum == 0) {
                    headerRow = true;
                }
                startRow(rowNum);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that works is that the main class is reading and parsing the spreadsheet, and using a "handler" class to do any transformation or output: it is the inner class named MyXSSFSheetHandler.

Look at the endElement() method of this class. You will see that it writes the cell values to "output" and also writes missing values if it is the end of a "row" element.

You can add a variable to this inner class (e.g. "int myRowCount = 0").

Then, during the endElement(), around each write to "output" wrap an if statement

```
if (myRowCount > 0)
{
  output.print... etc..
}
```

Finally, inside endElement, where it checks that the "row" has ended, increment the row-count.